# Interstitial ad displays undefined using react-native and admob

Tags: react-native, admob

I'm trying to solve a problem but I still can't figure it out.
I used what is in the official documentation and the method below made by me, but I still get undefined every time I initialize an ad

```
const startGame = () => {
    const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(TestIds.INTERSTITIAL, {
      keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
    });

    interstitial.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.LOADED, () => {
      interstitial.load();
    });

    interstitial.show();
  };
```

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={require('./assets/loss_screen.jpg')} // Înlocuiește cu calea către imaginea splash screen
        style={styles.image}
        resizeMode="cover"
      />
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.scoreText}>You lost ! Try again.</Text>
        <Text style={styles.scoreText}>Your score: {score}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => startGame()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Restart game</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

I even tried with async functions but in vain